# Azure webjob - how to use CI with node

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a scheduled web job and I would like to do Continuous Deployment with this job.  Travis is my CI service, and would like to be able to leverage it for this purpose.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First, I suggest relying on the newer CRON mechanism instead of the Azure Scheduler for the scheduling, as it will make CI smoother (details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON)).

When it comes to deploying the file, the answer depends on whether your Web App is only running your WebJob or also has a site. In the end, you want to make sure your WebJob files end up under `wwwroot\app_data\jobs\triggered\{job name}` (details [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs)).

Comment: the web app is ONLY running the webjob.  It is actually running 2 webjobs (same code, but different batchfiles to init them differently)

Comment: Is there a way I can have multiple batch files in the folder that is uploaded and tell the webjob which to run, or would I create 2 different web apps and have to push to them different batch files?

Comment: If you have two batch files and want each to run continuously, simply put each one in a different folder under `continuous`. Note that if there is ever an ambiguity within one webjob folder, you can add a run.cmd file which will always be the chosen one, and from which you can run whatever you want.

Comment: with using the new cron style scheduling, will this till work?  I have a run.bat and a run.cmd (one for each web job).

Comment: I corrected the folder name in my Answer as it needs to be `triggered` and not `continuous`. Yes, this will work fine with the new cron scheduling. It's as simple as dropping that extra file in there (and make sure your Web App has Always On enabled).